# NVD3 custom tooltip content

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

im trying to change tooltip in my NVD3 chart but unsuccesfuly.. So i need help from u and thanks for that..

my tooltip looks like this :
[image]

but i want to add date like Mon, Tue etc... I tried to add .

here is sample how should it looks like, just add Date up here and remove Total value but keep values of charts...

[image]

```
.tooltipContent()
```

but this doesnt work for me or i using it wrong in my code..

```js
   var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
        .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
        .showControls(false)
        .showYAxis(true)
        .showLegend(false)
        .rightAlignYAxis(true)
        .controlLabels({stacked: "Stacked"})
        .color(keyColor)
        .duration(500);

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%a')(new Date(d)) });
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('f'));

    chart.legend.margin({
                    top: 30
                });

    d3.select('#chart1')
        .datum(histcatexplong)
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .call(chart)
        .each('start', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                d3.selectAll('#chart1 *').each(function() {
                    if(this.__transition__)
                        this.__transition__.duration = 1;
                })
            }, 0)
        });

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
```

Comment: The code you showed us doesn't match to your screenshot. What exactly is the problem? Don't you know how to format "Mon" when having a timestamp or do you have styling issues?

Comment: Sorry i past my test code... Thats the code what i have(i edited the code now)... The first one picture is how it looks like now and i want to add a date to top of the tooltip, delete the total summary at the bottom just like the second screenshot